# Qt Creator failed on running program when linking /usr/local/lib

Tags: macos, qt, libpng

Given the following simple project:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

TARGET = ConsoleTest08
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib
```

With this simple *main.cpp* file:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

When running from *Qt Creator*, I have the following error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_png_create_info_struct
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libPng.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

It runs fine from the terminal.

Here is my config:

- OSX 10.9
- Qt 5.5.1 clang 64 biy
- Qt Creator 3.6.0

I lastely update to *Qt Creator 3.6.0* so I suspect a bug.

I have *libpng 1.6.21* installed via *brew* which seams to conflict with the *ImageIO* framework but I don't link explicitely none of them.

Any idea about what happened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my problem by unchecking this new *Add build library search path to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH* checkbox in my project *Run* section:

[image]

Comment: I'm glad this solved your problem, have you any idea what it did and how that solved it? Or what your issue actually was?

Comment: There might be some conflict between system library and the ones installed by homebrew.