# libsqlite runtime error in Qt Creator (macOS)

Tags: c++, macos, qt-creator

I built a C++ application using Qt Creator 5.0 on macOS 11.4 (Big Sur). The build system is CMake. The application is very simple; it just uses the standard library and OpenCV. I can run it normally on terminal but when I try to run it in Qt Creator, I get a weird runtime error  message complaining that libsqlite is missing.

```
15:28:37: Starting /Users/guel/projects/OpenCVSample/bin/umake/clang-12.0/x86_64/release/OpenCVSample ...
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
  Reason: Incompatible library version: CFNetwork requires version 9.0.0 or later, but libsqlite3.dylib provides version 0.0.0
15:28:37: The program has unexpectedly finished.
15:28:37: The process was ended forcefully.
15:28:37: /Users/guel/projects/OpenCVSample/bin/umake/clang-12.0/x86_64/release/OpenCVSample crashed.
```

My application actually has nothing to do with CFNetwork or libsqlite. What might be the cause of this error?

Comment: this seems like an issue with your macOS. CFNetwork is a system library. You may try to update to 11.5.2 and see if it magically resolves this.

Comment: Updating to 11.5.2 didn't solve the issue. I realized that the path `/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib` doesn't exist; actually when I do `find / -name "libsqlite3.dylib"` I get a different path: `/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.36.0/lib/libsqlite3.dylib` plus some other libsqlite.dylib in Miniconda under different conda environments.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390905/qt-creator-failed-on-running-program-when-linking-usr-local-lib) answer, I solved this by unchecking "Add build library search path to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH checkbox" in my project Run section.